# Using R to repeatedly replace words

Tags: r, loops, replace

I have a sentence and I printed it in two lines:

```
cat("Today is Monday and it is sunny.\nMonday is a sunny day\n")
```

and I have two lists:

```
day<-c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
weather<-c("sunny", "cloudy", "rainy", "stormy","sunny", "cloudy", "rainy")
```

I am trying to produce a text file which would contain the string variable above but with every day and weather variable in the lists.

So I would have:

```
Today is Monday and it is sunny.
Monday is a sunny day
Today is Tuesday and it is cloudy.
Tuesday is a cloudy day
Today is Wednesday and it is rainy.
Wednesdady is a rainy day
```

.... and so on.

I am wondering if this is possible in R.  I am a relatively new beginner of R so any explanation would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could construct a simple loop and print using `cat`.

```
for (i in 1:length(day)) {
    cat("Today is", day[i], "and it is a", weather[i], "day.\n")
    cat(day[i], "is a", weather[i], "day\n")
}

# Today is Monday and it is a sunny day.
# Monday is a sunny day
# Today is Tuesday and it is a cloudy day.
# Tuesday is a cloudy day
# Today is Wednesday and it is a rainy day.
# Wednesday is a rainy day
# Today is Thursday and it is a stormy day.
# Thursday is a stormy day
# Today is Friday and it is a sunny day.
# Friday is a sunny day
# Today is Saturday and it is a cloudy day.
# Saturday is a cloudy day
# Today is Sunday and it is a rainy day.
# Sunday is a rainy day
```

This loops through all elements of your vector and it accesses each day and weather based on the index.

```
Day: "Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday" "Saturday" "Sunday"
Index:  1         2          3           4         5         6        7
```

At the first iteration of the loop, `i` is set to `1`, and `day[i]` is `"Monday"`. Likewise, `weather[i]` is `"sunny"` since `"sunny"` is the first element in the `weather` vector. That pattern is repeated over the whole vector.

So at the first iteration, the first sentence is

```
cat("Today is", "Monday", "and it is a", "sunny", "day.\n")
```

By default, `cat` separates consecutive values with a space. So this prints exactly the sentence we're looking for. The same is done for the second sentence.

Answer (score 2):

```
day<-c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
weather<-c("sunny", "cloudy", "rainy", "stormy","sunny", "cloudy", "rainy")
```

`sprintf` can be used to insert strings into other strings:

```
txt1 <- sprintf("Today is %s and it is %s.",day,weather)
txt2 <- sprintf("%s is a %s day",day,weather)
```

Now interleave the results (stick them together as rows of a matrix and then extract the elements column-wise -- there are other ways to do this, but this is a useful quick-and-dirty way):

```
c(rbind(txt1,txt2))
```

You could use `cat()` with `sep="\n"` or `paste()` with `collapse="\n"` to put the resulting vector into a single newline-separated result ... or just use `writeLines()` to send the vector of results to the text file.